# azure-pipelines.yml with in a job, run next step only when previous step failed

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Currently we have below code in my azure-pipelines.yml, We want to run sonarqube_publish_retry only when sonarqube_publish is failed. Tried adding a condition in the sonarqube_publish_retry step with `condition: failed()` but it is not working as expected. Any thoughts?

```
stages:

- stage: SonarQube_Scan
  jobs:
  - job: SonarQube
    - task: SonarQubePublish@5
      continueOnError: true
      displayName: 'Publish SonarQube results'
      name: 'sonarqube_publish'
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

    - task: SonarQubePublish@5
      displayName: 'Retry Publish SonarQube results'
      name: 'sonarqube_publish_retry'
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Comment: Rather than have a seperate step to retry the publish, you could try adding retryCountOnTaskFailure: to automatically try the publish task again. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-195-update#automatic-retries-for-a-task)

Answer (score 2):

When using `continueOnError`, and the step throws an error, the job status is set to `SucceededWithIssues`. As you can see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions), the `SucceededWithIssues` status will **not** be picked up by the by the `failed()` but by the `succeeded()` function, that's why your code doesn't work. Instead, in the condition, check the `Agent.JobStatus` variable whether it equals to `SucceededWithIssues`:

```
stages:
- stage: SonarQube_Scan
  jobs:
  - job: SonarQube
    - task: SonarQubePublish@5
      continueOnError: true
      displayName: 'Publish SonarQube results'
      name: 'sonarqube_publish'
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

    - task: SonarQubePublish@5
      displayName: 'Retry Publish SonarQube results'
      name: 'sonarqube_publish_retry'
      condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidCox88, I have added retryCountOnTaskFailure field and it works perfectly.